# Separation of variables, Homogeneous or Exact Differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I've just encountered these three, during exams of course they don't tell you which one is to use, if you need to use separation or homogeneous or exact. I was just wondering is there like a technique where I can just stare at it and know already what to use? I usually get like 8 questions in an hour and I'm having a hard time finishing it all.

Comment: The best way to recognize these is to practise as many as possible.

Comment: These methods are not exclusive so when you choose one, it's probably wise to consider them in order of difficulty (=time consumption):  separable<homogeneous<exact.